# Do you prefer to store confirm password property in database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am designing a database and it has came to my mind to check entered password (for register page) with confirmed password in database as well as in programming layer.
Do you recommend it?
Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if the `password` itself should be stored in the database?

Comment: @J.D. Definitely not. I mean the confirmed password field.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what do you plan to store in the "confirmed password field" if not the password.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the "*confirmed password field*" is?

Comment: @J.D. when you want to register on a website, you should enter your password twice. Like when you confirm your email address. Now my question is that should I check password match in the database layer by checking two columns in my db?
Is it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but let's consider a signup form. It is customary to ask for password confirmation, then when the user submits the form, the backend checks that both password fields do match. If there was some issue like incomplete data, you show a message back to the user.
Otherwise, if no other errors were found, you proceed to save the record to the DB - the password of course should be **hashed** and not stored in plain text.

But until the form is submitted without errors, you save nothing to the DB. At least I don't see why you would.

You can save session state though, that's what cookies are for.

To sum up, only one field is need for the password (in *hashed* form). The password confirmation field is simply to minimize the risk of incorrect input, but it's no longer useful after signup has completed.

Comment: @Commander Thanks for elaborating in the comments. This is basically the answer you're looking for. The database has no part in validating the password of new registration. You just need to take the password the user inputs into the form, hash it, do the same for the `confirm password` field, and compare that the hashes match, in your application's backend code. If they do then you save the hash to the database otherwise let the user know that their passwords don't match.